# Stereograms: Decoding an image from a pattern

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

Inside this pattern there is an image of a kettle. You can see it if you really focus. I'd like to know if I can use Matlab to decode this pattern? Give me some tips or code samples.

[image]
[image]

Comment: haha I believe you, its just I cant see it XD. It woudl be really great if you could detecct that with matlab. But I really doubt it will be easy! good luck!!

Comment: I am with @AnderBiguri, I can't see it at all. Even when I compare it with your second picture. Do you know anything about how this picture (and the background) are created? If you had a function for it or another picture with just the background it could be done easily. Here the only idea I would have is to get the approximated/interpolated value of each pixel by analyzing the adjactend pixels and check if that value fits with the given value in the picture, but not sure IF that works and how to get started. Intersting question

Comment: "Matlab can even make your dinner, if you know how to use it" @AnderBiguri

I dont think that it will be easy eatiher. But it would be really nice.

Comment: @AlexAnis whom are you quoting about making dinner? That "joke" could have been from my introduction into informatics profesor

Comment: @TheMinion It's on AnderBiguri's profile

Comment: @AlexAnis haha you got me

Comment: I can't see the kettle either, found a giraffe though

Comment: http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2013/07/12/how-to-decode-stereogram-by-photoshop/

Comment: Actually seeing stereograms is really easy once you've got the knack of it: Essentially you have to either cross-eye or lapse-eye look at it, so that the semi-regular patterns get "indexed off-by-1" between  the eyes. With some practice you can just "relax" your eyes (as if you look into the distance) the picture get's blurry, but you can still make the off-by-one alignment, and with that done you can accomodate back to sharp vision without loosing the off-by-1 eye positioning. **Yes there is a kettle inside, specifcally the infamous Utah teapot, plus some other geometry (cup, window).

Comment: -1 Though it's an interesting problem, the question doesn't show a minimal effort to solve it.

Comment: @karlphillip That is because I didn't know anything about stereograms. I wanted to get some tips to get me started so that I could start investigating. I'm already aware of how SO works.

Comment: @karlphillip Do not agree with your point of view. The OP doesn't ultimately ask for codes. The OP is wandering IF it is possible to solve such a task with MATLAB and if so WHICH recommendations you have to get started. So to say no minimal effort is right, but understandable.

Comment: @TheMinion I do not agree with your disagreement. If you think that part of what I said is true (regarding the *minimal effort* thing) then it means that you **partially agree** with me. ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Warning

This answer will not attempt to solve this programatically ... Instead it focuses on letting Matlab do the eye crossing* for you however you still need to decide how far* to cross them...

* *this terminology sounds wrong but I'm just going to go with it*

### Method

Simply shifting the image and subtracting it from the original should give reasonable results, choosing the shift however is the tricky part, but once you know it something as simple as `imData-circshift(imData,[shiftY,shiftX,0])` should give a good image...

[Here is a crude but simple GUI wrapper](http://pastebin.com/Qy7eiYfa) for the line of code above... (just run the function with an image file name as an argument)

It doesn't give great results for the given image but it works better on [some of these](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=magic+eye&gws_rd=ssl)

### Example

*Initial Image*

[image: Unsolved Magic eye]

*After a little playing*
[image: solved Magic eye]

Comment: +1 - I could never for the life of me see what's behind stereograms.  People saying all you need to do is focus have no idea what they're talking about.  Thanks for this idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think "you can see it if you really focus" is not correct. In my oppinion you rather have to defocus to see the hidden image. You have to focus on a thought object that lies behind the image plan.

To extract it with matlab, I would suggest to try some stereo algorithms. Correlate each line of the image with itself and find repetitions. This is the same way our brain sees the hidden image.

Comment: http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2013/07/12/how-to-decode-stereogram-by-photoshop/

Comment: I will be back when the program is done.

Comment: Actually you have to cross the eyes so as to see farther that the image plane and let every eye look at locations shifted by a period of the pattern (or more ?). It is possible to stay focused at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a stereo vision problem: if you cross your eyes correctly you will see the object in 3D. i suggest you have a look at disparity maps: for instance the disparity matlab function (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/vision/ref/disparity.html)
computes a 3D image from a pair of 2D image.